# Error open same view that send local notification

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, firebase

I Try to open specific View controller from local notification.. I put Actions and category and **Function of scheduleNotification** in **AppDelegate** .. 
When I try to open any ViewController (storyboard) Every thing seems Ok !
Unless when open ViewController (storyboard) That have function for sending notification ..

This is the function in the ViewController when I comment it, it Work!:

```
func expiredDate() {
    print("start")

    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd" //format the date to match how it's stored in Firebase
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "/Data/\(user!.uid)/")




    ref.child("EssentialsList").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let snap = child as! FIRDataSnapshot
            let dict = snap.value as! [String: Any]

            let eventDateStampString = dict["date"] as! String
            let endDate = formatter.date(from: eventDateStampString)

            let calendar = NSCalendar.current as NSCalendar

            var comps = DateComponents()
            comps.day = -5
            let exDate = calendar.date(byAdding: comps,
                                       to: endDate! , options: [])

            print(" expired date: \(String(describing: exDate))")

            let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
            delegate?.scheduleNotification(at: exDate!)

                       }
    })

}
```

Here the code for handle Action in AppDelegate:

```
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    switch response.actionIdentifier {
    case "ViewEss":
        print("ViewEss")
        //       let myTabBar = self.window?.rootViewController as! UIViewController
        self.window?.rootViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HelloID")

    case "ViewCar":
        print("ViewCar")
        //       let myTabBar = self.window?.rootViewController as! UIViewController
        self.window!.rootViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CarAll")


    default:
        print("Other Action")
        self.window?.rootViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainAndCar")


    }

}
```

}

The Error cone After Open the notification :

> ViewEss
>   fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   2017-05-08 00:00:03.291397 ade-mc-trial[2164:659918] fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   (lldb)

Comment: Not really enough information to nail it down as it's not clear what the order of those functions is... Does ViewEss print in the console? If so, self.window or self.storyboard are probably nil. I would insert some code right after the print("ViewEss") line to see if either of those are nil. Otherwise, one of your Firebase nodes may be missing the 'date' child.

Comment: Yeah , print  ViewEss in console. What the code you want insert ?

Comment: Add code to see what optional thats being unwrapped is nil. For example if the self.storyboard! is a possibility since the other two a self.storyboard?. Adding guard statements can really help with identifying unwrapping issues and protect against them.